# Counter-example for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, examples-counterexamples

let $F:[a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and non negative function. Is there exist an example of a $F(x)$ that $F^7(x)$ is not continuous at some point?
If not, could you explain why?
*my intuition says it does not exist because multiplying continuous functions is still continuous*

The question I asked was part of a bigger question im handling:
given the same $F$ I defined above: assuming the integral $\int_a^b{e^{F(x)}}$ converge, does the integral: $\int_a^b{F(x)^7}$ converge?
I'd like for a hint here because I'm kind of lost.
*my idea for this was that because $F(x)$ is non negative I could write: $\int_a^b{F(x)^7}=\int_a^b{e^{7ln(F(x))}}$ and then im missing a lemma why this could be proof*

Comment: What's a divergent function?

Comment: you're right, it's my mistake, changed it to continuous.

Comment: You are asking if there is an example of a continuous function $F$ such that $F^7$ is also continuous? Is that it?

Comment: that is not continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the second part: Since $F$ is nonnegative, $e^{F}\ge \dfrac{F^7}{7!}.$

Comment: So you mean that the integral $\int_a^b{F^{7}(x)/7!}$ is bounded by  $\int_a^b{e^{F(x)}}$  and therefore will converge? but from what I know, since it's improper integral (b is a point where F isn't defined) there's no lemma for it.

Comment: @YaronScherf Sure there is such a result, it's just the comparison test. We are dealing with integrals of nonnegative functions.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, the product of two continuous functions is continuous. You can deduce from this that, for each natural $n$, the product of $n$ continuous functions is continuous. In particular, the $7^{\text{th}}$ power of a continuous functions is continuous.